# Install all the dependencies without installing a package?

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

How do I install all the dependencies needed for the PHP package without installing the actual package for APT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the PHP package with all the dependencies, then uninstall the PHP package.

Comment: Heh, fair enough :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `apt-get`: `apt-get -s install name_of_PHP_package` shows what extra packages will be installed. To automate:

```
LC_ALL=C apt-get -s install |
awk '/^[^ ]/ {p=0}
     p {print}
     /^The following extra packages will be installed:/ {p=1}'
```

Using aptitude interactively: mark the PHP package for installation, press `g`, mark the automatically selected packages as manually requested with `m`, remove the initial package from the to-install list with `-`, and finally confirm the installation request with `g` again.

Comment: +1 for the aptitude solution. I'm certainly not apt enough about `apt`.